# Set field based on sum(value)

Tags: php, mysql

Apologies for ambiguous title

Given the following data..

```
  +------+------------+--------+
  |  ID  |  value     | used   |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1001 |    1       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1002 |    1       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1003 |    2       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1004 |    4       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1005 |    1       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1006 |    1       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1007 |    1       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1008 |    6       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
```

I would like to set the sum value of say 8, so the result would be ....

```
  +------+------------+--------+
  |  ID  |  value     | used   |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1001 |    1       |   1    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1002 |    1       |   1    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1003 |    2       |   1    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1004 |    4       |   1    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1005 |    1       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1006 |    1       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1007 |    1       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
  | 1008 |    6       |   0    |
  +------+------------+--------+
```

I would do this my going through each item adding it to a total value, similar to this

```
  $goal = 8;
  $select = "SELECT ID, value FROM table WHERE !used";
  $result = mysql_query($select);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
     $total = $total + $row['value'];
     if ($total => $goal) 
         { 
         $over = $goal - $total
         if ($over)
            {
            $id = $row['id'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(value,used) VALUES('$over',0)");         
            mysql_query("update table SET used = 1 WHERE id = '$id'")                 
            }  
          break;
         }
     $id = $row['id'];
     mysql_query("update table SET used = 1 WHERE id = '$id'")  
     }
```

So, pretty ugly. suggestions of a better method?

Comment: You'll get [told off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Besides "don't use `mysql_*` anymore"...around how large is your table?

Comment: thanks for the heads up, not very large, well at the moment

Comment: why was this down voted, it shows some research, seems clear to me.

Comment: what if you goal is 7? what IDs should you take?

Comment: `1001 -> 1004` would be set to `1`, `1` would be inserted back in the DB with a new `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
      $goal = 8;
      $used = Array()
      $select = "SELECT ID, value FROM table WHERE !used";
      $result = mysql_query($select);
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
         $total = $total + $row['value'];
         $used[] = $row['ID'];
         // Check for exact march
         if ($total == $goal) {
             // Loop through all used ID's to get an exact match
             foreach($used as $usedId) {
                mysql_query("update table SET used = 1 WHERE id = " . $usedId);                 
             }
             break;
         } elseif ($total > $goal) { // If over then insert as a new record
             $leftOver = $total - $goal;
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(value,used) VALUES($leftOver, 0)");         
             break;
         }
      }
```

What this doesn't answer is if the total is less than your goal - what happens then?

Comment: yep, but if it is not possible to get the exact value the remainder is inserted back into the DB

Comment: So if $goal = 5 in your example above it wouldn't match because the total would go from 4 to 8. Would 4 then get inserted into the table above?

Comment: Right ok, and 3 would get inserted into the table with ID 1009?

Comment: it is already predefined that total cannot be less than the goal.

Comment: Ok then - does this help solve your problem then or does it require more tweaks?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.value, IF(SUM(t2.value) > 8, 0, 1) used FROM used t1
  JOIN used t2
    ON t1.ID >= t2.ID
  GROUP BY t1.ID
```

Comment: Can I have some explanation in what is going on here?

Comment: This query will count SUM of values and check `used` field where SUM less then 9. If this query is OK, then rewrite it to UPDATE query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use old and deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead.

```
$goal=13;
$cache=0;
$idCache=0;
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT id,value FROM [table] WHERE used=0 ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $idCache=intval($row["id"]);
    $cache+=intval($row["value"]);
    if($cache>=$goal) break;
}
$result->free();
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("UPDATE [table] SET used=1 WHERE used=0 AND id<=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$idCache);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
if($cache>$goal)
{
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO [table] (value,used) VALUES (?,0)";
    $cache=$goal-$cache;
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$cache);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Explanation:

1. From your demo data I assumed that you want to fetch your data sorted by id ascending, so I query them all with an `ORDER BY` clause;

   (the `$mysqli->query` part)
2. Sum the result into `$cache` until it gets not less than `$goal`;

   (the `while` part)
3. Since we get the value in id-ascending order, we can safely mark all IDs not greater than the last row we get to be "used";

   (the `$mysqli->prepare` before `if` block)
4. If the sum is greater than goal, we added the "overflowed" value back into the table, with `used` marked as `0`, as you hinted in your code.

   (the `if` block)

Note that the above code does not take the "what if not enough value to sum up `$goal`" situation into account. You'll have to deal with that if it can be a real case.